# Installed GTA 5 Steam version greyed out, Discovering Existing Files, then completely redownloads game?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Yesterday I was playing GTA5 Steam Version just fine, 
today the "Grand Theft Auto V" font-color in my Steam Library isn't white anymore just greyed out, also the Installation button returned, all fine and good I thought, I had this Problem before, Steam would just find the existing files and I'm good to go **but** after the loading bar reaches the end it displays "Steam is now downloading GTA 5" which pretty much sucks, I mean it's 60GB come on...

Anybody else had this problem with another game perhaps?

Comment: Check your `SteamApps/Common` folder to see if GTA is still there, if it is, make sure Steam is downloading onto that partition, in case you have multiple.

Comment: Yes the GTA V folder is still there.

Comment: I've had this happen to half of my Steam library once. All files were present, but I couldn't get them to work. I re-installed all hundreds of GB...

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me since i was moving a couple of files around in my folder

Open steam and go to steam/settings/downloads

click on steam library folders

make sure the folder your games are in is selected properly